# jquery regex date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have an input box where the user can enter a string date, for example today or tomorrow. But now the next problem has arrived: 3 march or 8 january.

The input box has a dropdown menu, when the user types: "tod" => today, "jan" => "january" etc, when the user selects the dropdown item it will insert the text for them, however now the following question:

3 januari, or 03 januari, or 3       januari, as you can see it requires some regex, to check whether the first part was numeric? and then a space comes (for x amount of times since we cannot rely on users :P) and then the name of the month?

How can I do this?

Thanks for help already.

Comment: can you give an example of what you have already? perhaps using [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```javascript
"13 august".match( /\s*(\d+)\s+(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)/ );
```

After this you can do

```javascript
var day = parseInt( RegExp.$1, 10 );
var month = [
        'january',
        'february',
        'march',
        'april',
        'may',
        'june',
        'july',
        'august',
        'september',
        'october',
        'november',
        'december'].indexOf( RegExp.$2.toLowerCase() ) + 1;
alert( month + "/" + day );
```

Look [at this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JgBrK/).

Answer (score 0):

Just the regex would be something like this

```
[0-9]{1,2}\s\w*
```